# VS template doesn't copy files, which aren't displayed in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-templates

Visual Studio 2013. I create own template.

its `vstemplate`-file has such records:

```
<Folder Name="batch-build" TargetFolderName="batch-build">
  <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="1_debug-build-all-versions.bat">
  <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="2_debug-build-all-versions-with-Gallio-tests.bat">
  <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="3_debug-build-all-versions-with-NUnit-tests.bat">
  <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="4_release-build-all-versions.bat">
</Folder>
```

I need all this files would be copied into my new project, based on this template.

But the `csproj`-file of this template has some *conditions*:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="batch-build\1_debug-build-all-versions.bat" />
  <None Include="batch-build\4_release-build-all-versions.bat" />
</ItemGroup>

<Choose>
  <When Condition="'$(Build_With_Tests_Of)' == 'NUnit'">
    <ItemGroup>
      <None Include="batch-build\3_debug-build-all-versions-with-NUnit-tests.bat" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </When>
  <When Condition="'$(Build_With_Tests_Of)' == 'Gallio'">
    <ItemGroup>
      <None Include="batch-build\2_debug-build-all-versions-with-Gallio-tests.bat" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </When>
</Choose>
```

When new project created, by default the `Build_With_Tests_Of` property has the `Gallio` value. Therefore in Solution Explorer shows the `batch-build\2_debug-build-all-versions-with-Gallio-tests.bat` file. This is what I need. But if I will open the directory of my new project, than I see - the `batch-build\3_debug-build-all-versions-with-NUnit-tests.bat` file was not copyed. So, template don't copy files, which is not displayed in the Solution Explorer. But I need their copies complettely.

How to force a template to copy all files?

Comment: Still the case in 15.8.2. Setting the file to resource did not help.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Here's my solution:
Add the needed file to the solution. At it's properties tab, mark it as a resource.  Now, create you template.
Changing a file to resource will make the template copy that file (assuming you didn't include it at the solution in the first place because it should not be complied)

Hope this helps, this is the solution I used to include a AssemblyInfo_Template.cs file in a template project. (AssemblyInfo_Template.cs is used by SubWCRev.exe to overwrite AssemblyInfo.cs in order to include the revision number in AssemblyInfo.cs)